# Check if product belongs to category?

Tags: category, collection

I have a collection/array of ~4000 products(search results) and a category number and need to filter them.

What would be the most efficient way of checking whether a product belongs to a certain category?

Now I use:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
  $productCategories = $product->getAvailableInCategories();

  if(array_search($category, $productCategories) === false) {
   continue;
  };

  $filteredProducts[] = $product;   
}
```

$products may be an array or collection.

I would appreciate your input :).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
$isInCategory = in_array($category, $categoryIds);
```

If the `$category` variable is an object then do this:

```
$isInCategory = in_array($category->getId(), $categoryIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note about this

If product is assigned only to lowest level category, and the parent categories in higher levels are **anchor**, I guess `getAvailableInCategories` would be the way to get all categories where product is displayed, as `getCategoryIds` would return only that lowest level category, which could not be the expected result

About efficiency, I guess methods should run more or the less the same, but this is the way Magento checks if a product is in a category in module-rule

**\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Product\Abstract**

```
/**
 * Retrieve category ids where product is available
 *
 * @param int $productId
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getAvailableInCategories($productId)
{
    return $this->productCategoryList->getCategoryIds($productId);
}
```

Which ends running

**\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList**

```
/**
 * Retrieve category id list where product is present.
 *
 * @param int $productId
 * @return array
 */
public function getCategoryIds($productId)
{
    if (!isset($this->categoryIdList[$productId])) {
        $unionTables[] = $this->getCategorySelect($productId, $this->category->getCategoryProductTable());
        foreach ($this->storeManager->getStores() as $store) {
            $unionTables[] = $this->getCategorySelect(
                $productId,
                $this->tableMaintainer->getMainTable($store->getId())
            );
        }
        $unionSelect = new UnionExpression(
            $unionTables,
            Select::SQL_UNION_ALL
        );

        $this->categoryIdList[$productId] = array_map(
            'intval',
            $this->productResource->getConnection()->fetchCol($unionSelect)
        );
    }

    return $this->categoryIdList[$productId];
}
```