# Check if product exists within a specific category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, php, category, if

I want to **check whether a product exists within a specific category** and **if true show message**.

At the moment I am having to do this via strpos using the Name attribute value.

```
   <?php if (strpos($_product->getName(),"Hello") !==false): ?>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
     <p><i style="font-style:italic;">A message goes here.</i></p>
    </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Is there any way to do similar using either category name or ID?

Comment: see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46405/check-if-product-belongs-to-category

Answer (score 1):

Copy following code in your phtml file:

```
<?php $yourCatIds = array(1,2,3...);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
    echo '<li>' . $_product->getData('attributecode') . '</li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... does it matter that the category I am looking at is a parent category (i.e. the product is contained within child of a parent)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your product belongs to a specific *special* category id :

```
<?php
$productCategoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
$specialCategoryId=3;

?>
    
<?php if (in_array($specialCategoryId,$productCategoryIds)): ?>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
     <p><i style="font-style:italic;">A message goes here.</i></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... does it matter that the category I am looking at is a parent category (i.e. the product is contained within child of a parent)?

Comment: The product has to be a member of the category you are testing for.